# Is proving LHS - RHS $\gt 0$ a valid method of proof?

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

In a question such as

> Prove $(a^2+b^2)/2 \gt [(a+b)/2]^2$

is proving that LHS - RHS $\gt 0$ a valid method of proof? (Eventually getting $[(a-b)^2]/4 \gt 0$)

Would I be better off using proof by contradiction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x > y \iff x-y>0$ so you're fine.

Comment: Of course, it is a valid proof. However, you want your sign to be $\geq$, since as stated the inequality is false for $a=b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case and in most other cases, the best strategy to prove an inequality of type $$F(x,y) \geq G(x,y)$$ is to perform operations on it to obtain an equivalent inequality of the form $$H(x,y)^2 \geq 0$$ or other well-known inequalities such $AM\geq GM$ ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)), Cauchy-Schwarz inequality ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#Special_cases)) and others.